# Analog to MS Access WITH statement in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, vba, linked-server

I have a linked server whose name is very long. I have a stored procedure that I need to execute that needs tables from that server. I don't want to have to type the server name over and over as it will make the code look rather ugly. I'd love something like the MS Access VBA With block, or something that accomplishes the same thing. I am unaware of any such capability in SQL Server. Does anything exist that could accomplish my goal?

```
WITH
    SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousServer.db1.dbo
        SELECT * FROM Table1
END WITH
```

Comment: You could look into synonyms. You would need one for each table but not that big of a deal.

Comment: Do you just need a [table alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)? You'd need to alias each long table name in each query, but depending on your queries that might be enough to make life easier. (Synonyms or views might be better, but with an alias you wouldn't need to create any extra objects on the server.)

Comment: @MattGibson You're probably right, I could probably just use a table alias and leave it at that. I'll just break out the FROM and JOIN statements a little more so that the code is clear...

Answer (score 3):

Nothing that maps exactly to how VBA works. You could do one of the following:

1. Use an alias in your query.

   ```
   select S.* from SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousServer.db1.dbo.Table1 as S;
   ```
2. Use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

   ```
   with MyLongTableName as select S.* from SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousServer.db1.dbo.Table1
   select * from 
   MyLongTableName;
   ```
3. Use a temp table:

   ```
   Select * into #MyTable from SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousServer.db1.dbo.Table1
   select * from #Mytable
   ```
4. Use a [`synonym`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) to create an "alias" for the table that's scoped to the current database (you'd only have to do this once, as it'll persist in the database)).

   ```
   use [db1];
   create synonym dbo.RemoteTable1 for SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousServer.db1.dbo.Table1
   ```

   Then in your stored procedure:

   ```
   select * from db1.dbo.RemoteTable1
   ```

Use caution with CTEs, as they're re-queried *each time* they're executed in a statement. Also, CTEs are only valid for the current statement, so if you have a series of queries that will all use it, you'll have to re-declare them for each.

The synonym might require a bit more maintenance if things change over time but it's pretty convenient and available to all users. However, reaching across the linked server is expensive so don't do this more frequently than necessary.

If you're going to reference this data in multiple queries in your stored procedure, pulling your data into a temp table (preferably with a well-defined set of criteria so it's as little data as necessary) for use in your stored procedure is *probably* the most appropriate solution.

The temp table won't have any indexes on it, so you may have performance issues there as well unless you create them explicitly. But you can use that same temp table across multiple queries in the same session.